# "ERROR in xx.js from UglifyJs Invalid assignment" when importing a module into another module

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, uglifyjs

I cannot post exact code due to NDAs, so I will do my best.
Javascript is not my string suit, but I took it up for my team.

#### Background:

I built a module which basically will perform a very simple task and can be imported as a dependency in other projects and then added into the project by adding the tag.

I wanted to keep this as lightweight as possible and let the app which was adding it in do the heavy lifting and have the imports to run and compile Angular code.

#### Code for SimpleApp:

Everything seems to work fine except for places marked with `/* Potential Issue */`

Within the simple module, I have a few file:
*simpleApp.js* -- the main js file which does the work necessary
*simpleApp.html* -- the html of simpleApp.js
*innerProvider.js* -- a module.service which does some work when called from the simpleApp.js -- this import seems to be the issue causer.

---

All within the companySimpleApp package:

*simpleApp.js:*

```js
import angular from "angular"
/* I believe this to be the issue */
import innerProviderModule from "./pathToFile/innerProvider /* Potential Issue */

/* Potential Issue */
angular.module('simpleApp', [innerProviderModule]).component('simpleComponent, {
    controller: ['$scope, 'innerProvider', ..., function($scope, innerProvider, ...) {

    /* does work */

}],
template: require("./simpleApp.html"),
bindings: {
    bind1: '@',
    bind2: '@'
}
```

*simpleApp.html:*

```html
<div>

do stuff
call stuff

</div>
```

*innerProvider.js:*

```js
import angular from "angular"


const innerProviderModule = angular.module('innerProvider', [])
    .service('innerProvider', function (%http, ...) {
        this.doWork = function (param1) {
            retStmt = doSomething(param1)
            return retStmt
        }
    });
export default innerProviderModule.name;
```

Everything here builds correctly and will do as is told. I am able to build this package as well as the one which uses it and have a working webpage with the simpleApp's services. However, this is when I host everything myself.

#### Code for Larger Service using SimpleApp:

In another project I have this listed as a dependency "simpleApp = 1.0" *this may be different than expected due to my company's internal workings, but this works*.
It appears in the node_module directory

I then have a module for the webpage which loads in simpleApp and has all of the other packages like angular, babel, uglify, webpack, etc:

```js
/* Potential Issue */
import "companySimpleApp/simpleApp.js"

export default angular
    .module("app", [otherDependencies, simpleApp])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $stuff){

        someMappingsForUrls
    });
```

```html
...
    <script src="../node_modules/companySimpleApp/simpleApp.js"></script>
...
```

and another html and js file which use the simpleApp

```html
<div>
<simpleApp bind1='{{value}}'></simpleApp>

</div>
```

#### Error:

Now, everything will run fine on my localhost and I can fully use the larger service using SimpleApp site with the simpleApp. However, when I build this (`npm run webpack`) on the service using simpleApp, I get the following error even though everything seems to run fine on my localhost:

```sh
ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Invalid assignment [bundle.js:146461,67]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ webpack: `webpack -p`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ webpack script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

........
```

The code seems to build when I remove the `import innerProviderModule from "./pathToFile/innerProvider` from `simpleApp.js` but I then get an error saying that innerProvider is an unresolved reference or something along the line.

What I am asking is for some help on why I may be seeing this error when I import the innerProviderModule I built. Do I need to add webpack and all that to my simpleApp project even though it all seems to run fine physically on my localhost?

Any help or ideas is very much so appreciated. Thanks!
Bumping this as I posted it late at night.

Edit: It seems to not like "=>" in the innerProvider which I have

Answer (score 1):

I built the package which uses the simpleApp with 'webpack -p' which was not done on simpleApp. So, what it looked like that happened was that the simpleApp was not minified or something and didnt like a few lines in the provider code (ie: "=>", "let", etc...)

So instead of having the simpleApp have more dependencies, I simply wrote code which would pass webpack -p.

You should also be able to just remove the "-p" flag

Hope this helps someone.